# Retrieve files protected by NQVault due to forgotten password

Tags: nqvault

I downloaded NQVault to my Samsung Galaxy S3 and I moved some videos to the vault. However, I couldn't get back the videos because I forgot my password. After trying many times to find out how to change the password, I became frustrated, so I deleted the app.

My question is, is there anyway for me to get my videos back from the app due to the fact it was deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, NQVault [does not really encrypt](https://ninjadoge24.github.io/#002-how-i-cracked-nq-vaults-encryption) the files, but simply does a byte-by-byte xor operation with a key that is generated from the password. Oh, and it does that only for the first 128 bytes. Since a byte can only take 256 different values, you can simply brute-force the key you need to "decrypt" your file.
The author of the [linked post](https://ninjadoge24.github.io/#002-how-i-cracked-nq-vaults-encryption) has even published the code for a brute force attack. All you need to do is to compile the c code, edit the bash script to recognize whatever mime type your videos are and then run the script.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

According to NQ [FAQ](https://help.nq.com/entries/23294821-What-can-I-do-if-I-forget-my-Vault-password-),

> NQ Mobile makes your privacy our top priority. Unfortunately, that
>   means your **NQ Mobile Vault password is kept secret, even to us**. If you
>   forget your password, **we have no way to get it back**; however, you can
>   use Vault Online to backup all of your Vault content (including call &
>   SMS history, photos & videos) to a secure private cloud storage, which
>   you can restore back onto your phone or a new phone.  You can set up a
>   new Vault password by uninstalling and reinstalling NQ Mobile Vault.
>   Please note, if you reinstall NQ Mobile Vault with a new password you
>   will not be able to access data you stored using your old password.